# How do i know if my Jenkins/Hudson is running the latest PMD version ( not the PMD plugin version )

Tags: plugins, jenkins, pmd

The latest PMD version is 5.2.3 (21st December 2014). But the PMD plugin installed on my Jenkins is of version 3.38. How do i know if this plugin is using PMD 5.2.3 for code quality checking. By the way i have configured Jenkins to use maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't run PMD directly. The [PMD Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin) is used for reporting on the PMD results. The actual version of PMD is in your Maven pom.xml file. Check what version of the [Maven PMD Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) you are referencing and update that as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the plugin's website ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin ) but  no where they have mentioned the PMD version that this plugin validates the code against. Installing the latest plugin should use the latest PMD version but still they should have mentioned it somewhere.